# Finding characters between parentheses with a .NET Regex

Tags: c#, regex

How can I  get `98` from the expression `$RetailTransaction.IsContainsTender(98)` using *Regex*?

Comment: Have you had a look at [.NET regexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)?

Comment: Is regex a requirement of the task? If this is the unchanging format of the string then it's certainly not a requirement enable success.

Answer (score 9):

As usual in such circumstances you should first ask yourself how the data will look like (with more than a single example) and what to expect from it.

The easiest route may be just the regex

```
\d+
```

But this will fail if there are more digits in the line than the ones you want.

You could take parentheses into account:

```
(?<=\()\d+(?=\))
```

This uses a lookbehind and lookahead assertion so that the number is the complete match (and not tucked away in a capturing group).

You can also use other context, e.g. the method name:

```
(?<=IsContainsTender\()\d+(?=\))
```

All of these things can make the regex more robust against unwanted data that might accidentally match, but that's a tradeoff only you can make because for some reason I have only a single example to work with here. If all you ever need is to match a `98`, then `98` is a valid regex and does what you want with above example. Hence my plea that you should think harder about cases you *want* to match and cases that might give you trouble with overly simplistic approaches.